# Clarification on proper flagging for what looks like live data

Tags: support, flags

I flagged a question like so:

> VBA Error :Could not find installable ISAM 1 asked Jan 15 at 19:15 by
>   Swapnil agrawal This post seems to have included a real user name and
>   password. I have edited them out, but I am not sure that this is
>   sufficient. I have not commented, because I do not want to draw
>   attention to the slip. – Jan 16 at 22:02   helpful

Because it seemed to have a real user name and password, and that seems to have been appropriate. Whereas flagging this question that may have had a real, or even seemingly real, credit card number was not appropriate:

> Select a value from drop down by providing a substring of that value
>   asked 5 hours ago by Hitendra Singh That looks horribly like a real
>   credit card number. I have edited, but it may not be enough. – 2 hours
>   ago   declined - I'll let you know once I've tried to use it.

When is it proper to flag data that appears to be live/real?

Comment: IMO, it is almost always proper.

Comment: That flag decline-message is wonderful.